# Enable wheel in mintty for cygwin comands: less and man

Tags: cygwin, less, scroll-wheel, man, mintty

I'm using mintty and cygwin. How to can I enable the mouse wheel inside less and man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supposed to work by default, but you might be falling foul of [mintty issue 262](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=262), where some mouse drivers don't deliver mousewheel events to the mintty window if they see an inactive scrollbar. A workaround is to remove the scrollbar on the *Window* page of mintty's options. The real fix would be to convince your mouse driver not to hide mouse events.