# Enable wheel in mintty (cygwin) for vim

Tags: vim, cygwin, mouse-wheel, scroll-wheel, mintty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable wheel in mintty for cygwin comands: less and man](https://superuser.com/questions/390340/enable-wheel-in-mintty-for-cygwin-comands-less-and-man)

How to enable the mouse wheel inside vim?
I'm using mintty and cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put "`:set mouse=a`" in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Great tip. FYI - I didn't need to do this on if I put in `~/.vimrc`. Just putting `set term=mintty` did the job on Cygwin. But your tip got it to work on my Mac.

Comment: Sadly, if I now highlight text and press Cmd-C, it erases the text.

Comment: There is a workaround but in my case I prefer copying over scrolling to be left alone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608161/copy-text-out-of-vim-with-set-mouse-a-enabled